# Reverting to a non-iPad App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I have a Universal app existing in the app store for a client.  The client wants to release an update just for the iPhone and ignore the iPad.

I said this wasn't possible because the app is already Universal, however, im not sure if I am right now.

- Can I release an update that reverted to a non-universal app?
- If so will the iPad customers get the update as a 2x app?
- Are there any other options?  Can I push an upstate just to iPhone customers?

Comment: I don't think you can do this as the iPad app will then not be able to update. If they want two apps like this I would advise you do them as separate projects and release them separately.

Answer (score 3):

if it is a universal app, then you can just change the iPhone code and leave the iPad code as it is. Both devices will get possibility for an update. I'd recommend adding something like

*Update for iPhone side, nothing changed for iPad*

to the release notes.

Answering your questions:

- No idea, but I wouldn't do it
- I don't think so
- Other option: change only iPhone side and then test it on devices before publishing. That will show you if something will go wrong on iPad

I do believe one of the apps installed on my iPhone had something like that.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can revert to a non-universal app by making the appropriate changes to your project settings.  This will cause all devices to receive the update when released, and on the iPad the app will revert to the 'iPhone 2x' interface.  You cannot (as far as I can see) push an update to iPhone only.

Reverting to a non-universal app might upset some of your client's customers if they have become accustomed to using the iPad User Interface for the app when they find themselves back in the iPhone UI.

However - if the change you need to make is only to the iPhone User Interface, and doesn't affect the iPad UI or your application logic; Or if the change is to the application logic and won't break the iPhone or iPad UIs, you could still make that change and stay as a universal app ... In other words an iPhone UI update doesn't need to change or remove iPad UI functionality, and a logic-only change which doesn't break either of the UIs won't need you to revert to iPhone only even if that logic change only affects the iPhone.

If you need different behaviours within the app for iPhone and iPad, you can check which device your app is running on and carry out different functions automatically.

Basically, check what the update will affect in each of the UIs, and if the iPad UI won't break just leave it universal.

Comment: Agreed, obviously it's the simplest way to satisfy the customer while keeping end-user experience acceptable.

Comment: StackO Aberdeen Meetup 2012: See [SO Meetup Link](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/Aberdeen-GB/653922/#comment1228022) for more info. Seeing you are based in Aberdeen, please try to attend. I'll remove this comment tomorrow. Apologies, but there is no other way to contact on SO.